# Cloud Firestore Keeps re-downloading documents - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This happens in my main application
and
I replicate it with the given codelabs:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/index.html?index=..%2F..index#10

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Baby Names',
     home: MyHomePage(),
   );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() {
   return _MyHomePageState();
 }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Baby Name Votes')),
     body: _buildBody(context),
   );
 }

Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

     return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
   },
 );
}

Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
   return ListView(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
     children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
   );
 }

 Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
  final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);

   return Padding(
     key: ValueKey(record.name),
     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
     child: Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
       ),
       child: ListTile(
         title: Text(record.name),
         trailing: Text(record.votes.toString()),
         onTap: () => print(record),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}

class Record {
 final String name;
 final int votes;
 final DocumentReference reference;

 Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
     : assert(map['name'] != null),
       assert(map['votes'] != null),
       name = map['name'],
       votes = map['votes'];

 Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
     : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

 @override
 String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

Only plugin i use is the **cloud_firestore 0.9.5+2**.You need to be patient with this testing process please. You will not see the issue right away. Run the app first, set this project up. You can follow the directions in the given codelabs. Once everything is set up on front end and backend(create documents on firstore). Go have a lunch break, dinner, play video games or hang out with friends. Come back after 1 hour. Run the app, you will be incurred charges for those reads as new. Do it again, come back 1 hour and it will happen again

How to replicate it in real life:
Start this app by given code from codelabs. Run it, it should incur 4 document reads if you stored 4 documents into the firestore.

Start it up again. No reads are charged. Great it works! but no, it really doesnt.

**I wake up next day and open up the app, im charged 4 reads.** Okay maybe some magic happened. I restart it right away and no charges incur(great!). **Later in 1 hour, i start up the app and I get charged 4 reads to display the very same 4 documents that have not been changed at all.**

The problem is, on app start up. It seems to be downloading documents from the query snapshot. No changes have been made to the documents. This stream-builder has been previously run many times.

**Offline mode(airplane mode), the cached data is displayed with no issues.**

in my main application for example, I have a photoUrl and on fresh App start, you can see it being loaded from the firestore(meaning downloaded as a fresh document thus incurring a READ charge). I restart my main application, no charges are made and photo does not refresh(great!). 1 hour later i start up the app and charges are made for every document I retrieve(none of changed).

**Is this how cloud firestore is supposed to behave?**
From what I have read, its not supposed to behave like this :(

Comment: You should edit the question to show the relevant code and how the queries are actually being performed, so we can all be in agreement about what your app is actually doing,

Comment: Also bear in mind that the Firestore console bills reads when you use it.

Comment: I know it does as I noticed that. I stopped looking at the console. I look at 2 hours after I use my app. Close my app and go back(after 2 hours) to console to look at the usage in the console and also in the appengine Quotas
I have been fighting against this for 1 month now but I think i need help

Comment: Also thank you for the quick response. If you get this code working and the backend works as it is supposed to. Please respond with the flutter channel, plugin version for cloudstore, gradle settings etc. I would try to replicate it and then respond after testing again

Answer (score 6):

You should not do actual work in `build()` except building the widget tree

Instead of code like this in build

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
```

you should use

```
Stream<Snapshot> babyStream;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  babyStream = Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots();
}

Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: babyStream,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

     return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
   },
 );
}
```

The FutureBuilder docs don't mention it that explicitly but its the same

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
>   State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or
>   State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
>   State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
>   FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
>   FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
>   the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I tried this but as and still the same issue testing few hours later
Stream<QuerySnapshot> babyStream;
I launch the app, i check back later on appengine and I am charged 4 reads for 4 documents. Okay no problem. I restart the app. No charges(great!)
I start up the app again 1 hour later and AGAIN i am charged for 4 reads. Still an issue. Can you please check this? run this on your side. Run the app>wait 1 hour> run it again. Check if it keeps charging reads. Thank you for your time

Comment: Widgets can be re-created when you navigate away and back, ... the the state is lost and data is fetched again. It's better to store the values outside widgets (global variable, Redux, ...) and only fetch from the server when the data is not yet stored.

Comment: Why does the Firestore caching work for 30 minutes to 1 hour(even on app restarts)(then all of a sudden the internal cache is redundant and forces firestore to redownload all documents as new queries? Isnt checking the backend supposed to be handled by firestore plugin? Im sorry but you gave me a very vague answer

Comment: I'm not aware of such a time limit and don't know what could cause this behavior. I'd expect that to be a behavior from the Flutter app not Firebase (plugin or server) but again don't know where this 1/2h could come from.

Comment: okay, does this piece of code i posted work alright in your environment? I just want to confirm that it works for others so this can help me troubleshoot. Thank you

Comment: I have no firesore set up and it depends where in your app the widget is located. Just move the code out of widgets to ensure it's not in any way dependent on widgets lifecycle.